# Can Lua talk to Hadoop?

Tags: lua, hadoop, mapreduce

Can I use the **Lua** programming language for **[Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org)**?

If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely :) You can use Hadoop streaming like this:

Create mapper and/or reducer scripts in lua that read from stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
while true do
  local line = io.read()
  if line == nil then break end

  # Do something with the incoming row

end
```

And then run your job like:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper myMapper.lua \
    -reducer myReducer.lua \
    -file /local/path/to/myMapper.lua
    -file /local/path/to/myReducer.lua
```

Here, you specify your mapper and reducer scripts using `-mapper` and `-reducer` and ship both scripts with `-file` to your distributed cache, so all task trackers have access to it.

When running with streaming, you need to make sure that `lua` is available on all the machines that run task trackers.

Some time ago, we experimented using `luajit` (which is horribly fast) for streaming from Pig. If you use Pig, you can do something like:

```
 OP = stream IP through `/local/path/to/script`;
```

This is not the same as using lua as a mapper or reducer, but depending on where your operation happens, the output from the mapper or reducer is streamed through the script.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Lua, nor the streaming side of Hadoop - So this is merely a suggestions, not sure if it will work:

Take a look at http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/ and use Lua inplace of Python?

If I was going to attempt to do what you are asking, that would be my starting point.